# Merge multiple csv file with same header using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having multiple csv files in a folder with data like below

**file1**

```
"Index","Response","Status","Time"
"32190","2","Succeeded","2023-01-18 08:31:34.9"
"32189","3","Succeeded","2023-01-18 08:26:34.9"
"32188","3","Succeeded","2023-01-18 08:21:34.9"
```

**file2**

```
"Index","Response","Status","Time"
"32190","2","Succeeded","2023-01-19 08:31:34.9"
"32189","3","Succeeded","2023-01-19 08:26:34.9"
"32188","3","Succeeded","2023-01-19 08:21:34.9"
```

Need to merge these files into a single csv with a one header

```
"Index","Response","Status","Time"
"32190","2","Succeeded","2023-01-18 08:31:34.9"
"32189","3","Succeeded","2023-01-18 08:26:34.9"
"32188","3","Succeeded","2023-01-18 08:21:34.9"
"32190","2","Succeeded","2023-01-19 08:31:34.9"
"32189","3","Succeeded","2023-01-19 08:26:34.9"
"32188","3","Succeeded","2023-01-19 08:21:34.9"
```

I have this below code but I am not able to get single header in it

```
$folder = 'D:\reports\daily_csv' 
$files = Get-ChildItem $folder\*.csv 
Get-Content $files | Set-Content "D:\Monthly\Merged_$prev_month.csv"
```

Please let me know what I need to add here to avoid multiple headers

Comment: Why not just: `Get-ChildItem $folder\*.csv |Import-Csv $_ |Export-Csv D:\Monthly\Merged_$prev_month.csv`?

Comment: I only just now realized that your (good) question is a duplicate.

Comment: Good point, @iRon, though you have an extra `$_` in there; additionally, a workaround for a bug is required in Windows PowerShell: `Import-Csv -LiteralPath (Get-ChildItem $folder\*.csv).FullName | ...` or - less robustly - `(Get-ChildItem $folder\*.csv).FullName | Import-Csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0) and an anonymous function. Note that [`.OpenText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.opentext?view=net-7.0#system-io-fileinfo-opentext) initializes the `StreamReader` with UTF8 encoding, if that's a problem you can use [`StreamReader(String, Encoding)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-string-system-text-encoding)) instead.

```
$folder = 'D:\reports\daily_csv'
Get-ChildItem $folder\*.csv | & {
    begin { $isFirstObject = $true }
    process {
        try {
            $reader  = $_.OpenText()
            $headers = $reader.ReadLine()

            if($isFirstObject) {
                $headers
                $isFirstObject = $false
            }

            while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
                $reader.ReadLine()
            }
        }
        finally {
            if($reader) {
                $reader.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
} | Set-Content path\to\mergedCsv.csv
```

Comment: Nice - didn't know that `System.IO.FileInfo` instances have an `.OpenText()` method.

Answer (score 3):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful plain-text-processing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75386720/45375) is definitely your best option, both in terms of performance, and in that it also preserves the formatting specifics (whether all fields or even only some fields are double-quoted or not).

A **slower, but more convenient alternative** that doesn't preserve the formatting specifics (which should *not* matter, however) is to use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)'s support for *multiple* input files, via its `-LiteralPath` parameter:

```bash
Import-Csv -LiteralPath (Get-ChildItem D:\reports\daily_csv -Filter *.csv).FullName |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 "D:\Monthly\Merged_$prev_month.csv"
```

Note that neither `-NoTypeInformation` nor `-Encoding utf8` are required anymore for [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), unless you need a different encoding (BOM-less UTF-8 is now the consistent default; if you do need a BOM, use `-Encoding utf8bom`).

Also note that a bug has been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+ that enables providing the `Get-ChildItem` results to `Import-Csv` *via the pipeline*:

```bash
# PS 7+ ONLY - a bug in WinPS prevents Get-ChildItem input to Import-Csv
Get-ChildItem D:\reports\daily_csv -Filter *.csv |
  Import-Csv |
  Export-Csv "D:\Monthly\Merged_$prev_month.csv"
```